# Extjs grid header is draw on top of other controls

Tags: extjs

See the image above, the grid header is always on top.

Here's the image:

[image]

This images is like a Menu. When I click the first one, open the menu in horizontal line. WHen I click the second (from top to botton) open the menu for this ˜group˜.
This is an iconic menu.

For the first time, its only shown the first column of icons (in this case "bar" and "favorites", and the grid is displayed correctly.
But once the "bar" button is clicked, the rest of line appears, but the grid header is on top.

This appears to be an absolute layout problem.

Comment: Can't see the image without logging in - can you rehost it? Thanks.

Comment: But what is the grid header in this image? These large icons?

Comment: The question inferred by the image is: Why is the grid header on top of the image? The only answer I can give is, put the grid header below the image... but I don't know what the image is doing there in the first place. Please provide more code and a question.

Comment: sorry the delay. I just edit this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not change extjs classes.

If you do that, will get problems in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is in the ext-all.css file.

the z-index property in the class:

```
.x-docked{
    position:absolute!important;
    z-index:1
}
```

seems to be the problem.

If I change to zero, it works.